# What's the controller in MVC pattern and why does it exist?

Tags: model-view-controller

While working with Unity, I realized that separating Model and View would make my code more readable and straightforward. Constructing the whole model, all I had to do is just create some UI and bind it to Model.

But I still don't understand what 'Controller' is, and why does it exist. I don't think I had trouble when I directly bound View to Model, not through Controller.

So the question is if we can bind View to Model directly, why do we need Controller? What's the benefit of having Controller between Model and View?

Comment: You say while working with Unity. Do you mean Unity3D as an application? Because MVC implementation inside Unity works differently than inside a regular web-application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the highest level the Controller is the link between the View (displaying the UI/UX) and the Model (creating and managing your database and its tables).
True, it is possible to write code without any Controller usage but your Views will quickly get very cluttered and each file will be full of logic that is much more nicely stored somewhere else *hint hint*.

The Controller (and Model and some other places such as helpers) is thus the perfect place to sort out all the back-end code so that all you need to do is send a single field or object to your View to display. 
An example is somewhat painful because by its nature the Controller is where you go to sort out your code as things get more complicated but this is a great article to get you on the right track! HTH

https://www.toptal.com/unity-unity3d/unity-with-mvc-how-to-level-up-your-game-development

Answer (score 0):

I don't have years of experience, but in my understanding controllers provide a bridge across view and models. While view contain the pretty part and models contain useful parts the controller do the calls of functions passing values from database to view or inputs to model. That provide a way to avoid lots of injection like class A calling class B, calling class C, etc.

You can put rule business in controllers or in view, but thats not the expected in MVC architecture. The first important thing (for me) in software programming is readability, whats MVC provide.

if you've interest, search for other architectures like MVVM, to compare then.